# Alike or like situations

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "like" or "alike" in my sentence?

"Sometimes I picture horrible scenes in my mind. They are alike situations from the Grudge."

Comment: @SorryI'mDumb - Sorry, but that's not right. Two things that resemble one another are _alike_, but we can't say that one is 'alike with' the other.

Comment: I apologize, I'll do my research before putting an answer next time.

Comment: Does "they" refer to the horrible scenes? You are trying to compare the horrible scenes to situations from the Grudge?